# Regular expression that matches given pattern and ends with optional number

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying to use a regular expression to match and extract parts of a URL.
The URL pattern looks like:

```
http://domain.abcdef/xyz/fe/fi/fo5/fu2m/123/
```

I intend to capture the following groups:

1. match and capture `xyz` (optional, but specific value)
2. match and capture `fe/fi/fo5/fu2m` (must exist, arbitrary value)
3. match and capture `123` (optional numeric value, which must appear at the end)

Here are expressions I have tried and problem encountered:

string1: `http://domain.abcdef/xyz/fe/fi/fo5/fu2m/123/`

string2: `http://domain.abcdef/xyz/fe/fi/fo5/fu2m/`

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[\da-z\.-]+)\.(?:[a-z\.]{2,6})(?:\/(xyz))?\/([\/\w]+)+(?:\/([\d]+))\/$
```

- makes number at end mandatory
- matches and captures all groups as required in string1 even when `xyz` is not included
- no match in string2 because there's no number at the end

  ```
   ^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[\da-z\.-]+)\.(?:[a-z\.]{2,6})(?:\/(xyz))?\/([\/\w]+)+(?:\/([\d]+))?\/$
  ```
- makes number at end optional
- captures only groups 1 and 2 in string1 and string2 . Number is matched along with group 2 in string2 as `fe/fi/fo5/fu2m/123`

My problem is how to capture groups 1, 2 and 3 in all scenarios incl. string1 and string2 (note: I am using PHP's `preg_match` function)

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend -- it defaults to PHP

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Technically it defaults to PCRE (which PHP uses).

Comment: Why do you need all three groups? You could use named capture groups and then you'd know what you have matched.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I have used various tools including regex101.com to test before asking for help here. I am using phpliveregex.com right now. I arrived at the issues  i explained here

Comment: @user3783243 I am fairly new to using regex can u illustrate what mean? have u tried to build an expression using the approach u just mentioned? If u have pls share it

Comment: You can add `?P<name>` to the start of a capture group and then the index will be that name, instead of the position it matched at. I think you may have modified the above regexs for formatting. Could you please edit them in the code blocks so they display as you have them?... or share a regex101 link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use `parse_url` first to extract the path from the url. Then all you have to do is to use a non-greedy quantifier in the second group :

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

if ( preg_match('~^\A/([^/]+)/(.*?)/(?:(\d+)/)?\z~', $path, $m) )
    var_dump($m);
```

This way, if the number at the end is missing, the non-greedy quantifier (from the second group) is forced to reach the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your suggestion on using the non-greedy quantifier did d magic. I just changed capture group 2 to (.*?) as you suggested. This had me tearing my hair out for days

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible to capture group 3 as an empty string when there is no number? Thanks again

Comment: @Remz: yes, for that you need to use a *branch reset* group. Change `(?:(\d+)/)?` with `(?|(\d+)/|())`

Answer (score 0):

Use a modified URL validator.

`'~^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/(xyz))?((?:/(?!\d+/?$)[^/]*)+)(?:/(\d+))?/?\s*$~'`

Group 1 is optional `xyz`
Group 2 is required middle
Group 3 is optional number at the end

Readable version

```
 ^ 
 (?! mailto: )
 (?:
      (?: https? | ftp )
      ://
 )?
 (?:
      \S+ 
      (?: : \S* )?
      @
 )?
 (?:
      (?:
           (?:
                [1-9] \d? 
             |  1 \d\d 
             |  2 [01] \d 
             |  22 [0-3] 
           )
           (?:
                \.
                (?: 1? \d{1,2} | 2 [0-4] \d | 25 [0-5] )
           ){2}
           (?:
                \.
                (?:
                     [1-9] \d? 
                  |  1 \d\d 
                  |  2 [0-4] \d 
                  |  25 [0-4] 
                )
           )
        |  (?:
                (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
           )
           (?:
                \.
                (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
           )*
           (?:
                \.
                (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,} )
           )
      )
   |  localhost
 )
 (?: : \d{2,5} )?
 (?:
      / 
      ( xyz )  # Optional specific value
 )?
 (  # Must exist, arbitrary value
      (?:
           /
           (?! \d+ /? $ )  # Not a numeric value at the end
           [^/]* 
      )+
 )
 (?:
      / 
      ( \d+ )  # Optional numeric value, which must appear at the end
 )?
 /?
 \s* 
 $
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 : len 46 ) 
http://domain.abcdef/xyz/fe/fi/fo5/fu2m/123/

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 21 : len 3 ) 
xyz  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 24 : len 15 ) 
/fe/fi/fo5/fu2m  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 40 : len 3 ) 
123  



 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 48 : len 42 ) 
http://domain.abcdef/xyz/fe/fi/fo5/fu2m/

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 69 : len 3 ) 
xyz  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 72 : len 18 ) 
/fe/fi/fo5/fu2m/

 **  Grp 3 -  NULL
```